# Windows Phone with XML - Display specific TAGs

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone

I'm developing an app, my "ListBox" displays information an XML file, get the information and display in "TextBox". But i do not want that the "ListBox" and "TextBox" show all XML TAGs.

First as it is now. Second as it should be:

http://infassteste.url.ph/ats.png

http://infassteste.url.ph/dps.jpg

My XML:

```
<produtos>
<produto>
<codigo>1</codigo>
<descricao>Janela</descricao>
<valor>100.00</valor>
</produto>

<produto>
<codigo>2</codigo>
<descricao>Porta</descricao>
<valor>1000.00</valor>
</produto>

<produto>
<codigo>3</codigo>
<descricao>Cimento</descricao>
<valor>10.00</valor>
</produto>

<produto>
<codigo>4</codigo>
<descricao>Arame</descricao>
<valor>60.00</valor>
</produto>
</produtos>
```

My Xaml file:

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Quantidade:" Margin="6,235,326,373"/>
        <TextBox MaxLength="3" InputScope="Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="71" Margin="135,215,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="86" Name="Qtd"/>
        <Button Content="Adicionar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="279,212,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148" Click="Button_Enviar"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,322,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Lista de Produtos:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="166"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" 
             Height="192" Width="456" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             BorderThickness="5"
             Padding="5"
             BorderBrush="Blue"
             Background="Black"
             FontSize="30"
             />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtList" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="267" Margin="0,357,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"/>

    </Grid>
```

My Code:

```
namespace InfamatPocket
{  

public partial class Produtos : PhoneApplicationPage
{


    public Produtos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();



        try
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(store.OpenFile("im.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

            this.listBox1.ItemsSource = from query in doc.Descendants("produto") select query.Value;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }




    private void Button_Enviar(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String dedos = " " + Qtd.Text + " | " + listBox1.SelectedItem;
        String dados = "\nProduto: " + listBox1.SelectedItem + "\nQuantidade: " + Qtd.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(dados);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dados))
        {
            txtList.Text += dedos + "\n";
        }

       // this.listBox2.ItemsSource = "Quantidade:" + Qtd.Text + " | " + listBox1.SelectedItem;



    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your LINQ query return a model having two property, `descricao` and `valor` for example (I'm using anonymous type here for the sake of simplicity) :

```
listBox1.ItemsSource = from query in doc.Descendants("produto") 
                       select new
                       {
                          descricao = (string)query.Element("descricao"),
                          valor = (string)query.Element("valor")
                       };
```

Setup `<ItemTemplate>` for `ListBox` so each item in `ListBox` able to display multiple values in the way we want :

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" 
         .....
         .....
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding descricao}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding valor}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: for display only TAG "descricao" in my "TextBox", is it possible?